# PHP no me reconoce la tabla de mi base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

mi base es: prueba, mi tabla: usuario, dentro de la tabla tengo dos usuarios nombre y contraseña, cuando ingreso el nombre y contraseña correctos para que acepte el usuario me muestre un mensaje de exito, pero me sale este mensaje

> Error conexionSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'prueba.usuario' doesn't exist...

me dice que la tabla usuario no existe en la base de datos prueba cuando está--- quien me puede dar una solución a esto

```
try{

    $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba','root','');


    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    $sql="select * from prueba.usuario WHERE usuario= :nom AND contrasena= :contra ";


    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);


    $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["nom"]));
    $pasword=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["contra"]));


    $resultado->bindValue(":nom", $login);
    $resultado->bindValue(":contra", $pasword);

     //ejecutamos la funcion sql
     $resultado->execute();

     $numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount();

     if ($numero_registro !=0) {
     echo "<h2>Estas Registrado</h2>";

     } else {
         header("location:diseño_IngresoA1.php");
         exit();
     }     
}catch(Exception $e){
    die("Error conexion" . $e->getMessage());
} 
?>
```

Comment: si es lo mismo. pero no ejecuta el mensaje de estas registrado cuando pongo los datos correctos

Comment: Si usas consultas preparadas no tienes que aplicar filtros a los datos, eso lo hace la consulta preparada. He visto casos en que el uso de estas funciones produce resultados erróneos. Prueba a crear las variables así simplemente: `$login=$_POST["nom"];
    $pasword=$_POST["contra"];`. El uso de `htmlentities`  y de `addslashes` no tiene absolutamente ningún sentido aquí. Otra cosa importante sería aplicar un charset adecuado a tu conexión. Para ello puedes crear un array donde pongas las configuraciones suplementarias y se lo pasas como último parámetro en el constructor. Algo así: ...

Comment: ...         Este sería el array: `$options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
        );` y luego: `$base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba','root',$options);` esto te evita tener que seguir seteando el objeto con `setAttribute` y establece configuraciones muy importantes para PDO, como son el charset. y desactivar las preparaciones emuladas.

Answer (score 1):

Primero te recomiendo que seas mas ordenado al momento de realizar preguntas, y coloques bien el código para que se pueda entender, y no sea mal vista tu pregunta.

Ahora, te recomiendo uses solo el nombre de la tabla en la consulta, se supone que estas conectado a la base de datos prueba.

Que utilices las clausulas de MySQL en letras mayúsculas.

Utiliza el método bindParam para bindear los datos.

Prueba con esto:

```
try
 { 
  $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba','root','');
  $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $sql="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = :nom AND contrasena= :contra";

  $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

  $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["nom"]));
  $pasword=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["contra"]));

  $resultado->bindParam(":nom", $login);
  $resultado->bindParam(":contra", $pasword);

  // ejecutamos la funcion sql 
  $resultado->execute();

  $numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount();

  if($numero_registro>0){
   echo "<h2>Estas Registrado</h2>";
  } else {
   header("location:diseño_IngresoA1.php");
   exit();
  }
 }catch(Exception $e){
  die("Error conexion" . $e->getMessage());
 }
?>
```

Comment: utilizo binValue por que comparo marcadores y no parametros como binParam. probe el codigo que me mandaste y me sigue mandando el mismo mensaje: Error conexionSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'prueba.usuario' doesn't exist

Comment: con bindParam funciona igualmente para los marcadores. Si te sigue dando ese error, es porque la tabla usuario no existe en tu base de datos. Chequea que todo este bien en tu base de datos

Comment: para mi hay un problema de conexion con la base de datos, estoy conectandome de manera PDO, creando consultas preparadas inyeccion sql... la BD prueba la utilizo en las demas consultas y no da error, en la tabla usuario la tengo creada, dos usuarios registrados para que me de el ok o si esta mal algun dato de ingreso me reediriga a la pagina inicio de volver a registrar, pero me marca que no existe la tabla. me esta matando esto, desdde hoy buscando el error y nada  che.... que sera por q no me reconoce php mi tabla? para mi es en la conexion q nose que sera

Comment: notaste algun error en mi conexion? me conecto en local, sin pasword, solo el nombre de la base de datos tengo que agregar no es algo complejo.... me esta re matando la cabeza de pensar y nada

Comment: prueba
    Nueva
    articulos
    clientes
    empleados
    facturaOculta
    sucursales
    usuario                                                                                                                        esta es mi base de datos

Comment: cambia el nombre del campo usuario a user, en tu tabla usuario. y del mismo modo cambias el nombre del campo en la consulta. prueba y me avisas

Comment: sigue el mismo error, no reconoce la tabla... la conexion esta bien. no necito un archi de conexion aparte donde especifique, o solo que esta line esta bien?                                                                                          $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba','root','');
  $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); falta algo mas para la conexion?

Comment: Haz la conexión en un archivo aparte. y en el archivo de la consulta haces un require('conexion.php'); a ver que pasa

Comment: el require lo coloco dentro del try?

Comment: try{
        $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba','root','');
          $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (Exception $e){
            die('Error Conexcion ' . $e->getMessage());
        } finally {
            $base=NULL;        
   }
        ?>

Comment: me pone conexion exitosa el mensaje que se encuentra dentro del try no tiera exception. pero me da este error:La conexcion tuvo exito
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso_PHP\Base_Datos\Login\programa.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso_PHP\Base_Datos\Login\programa.php on line 22

Comment: el require tienes que ponerlo en el archivo donde haces la consulta. luego de abrir la etiqueta php. <?php require('conexion.php');  aqui lo que sigue de codigo pero sin el try?>